# How to get Paypal Transaction ID in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the transactions id on thankyou.php page but WC_Order Object  does not have paypal transcation id.

WC_Order Object : -

```
WC_Order Object
(
    [order_type] => simple
    [id] => 49
    [post] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 49
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Order – January 8, 2016 @ 01:55 PM
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => wc-pending
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => order_568fbfcc2b0f2
            [post_name] => order-jan-08-2016-0155-pm
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/lfdemo/?post_type=shop_order&p=49
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => shop_order
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [order_date] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
    [modified_date] => 2016-01-08 13:55:24
    [customer_message] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [post_status] => wc-pending
    [prices_include_tax] => 
    [tax_display_cart] => excl
    [display_totals_ex_tax] => 1
    [display_cart_ex_tax] => 1
    [formatted_billing_address:protected] => 
    [formatted_shipping_address:protected] => 
)
```

I need some help! so please drop a comment with a solution!

Comment: When did you pull this order object?  It shows the status as pending.  The transaction ID doesn't come back into the order until the IPN triggers, which happens after the payment is completed.  Are you sure you're not just checking it too soon?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I write trigger in PayPal IPN instead of doing it within WooCommerce.

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I am looking for a solution too.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction ID is part of the post metadata...

$transaction_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_transaction_id', true);

Answer (score 1):

Better to go through the API:

```
global $woocommerce;

//Retrieve the order
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

//Retrieve the transaction ID
$transID = $order->get_transaction_id();
```